# Spinner Contents in Android

Tags: java, android

When you work with spinners in android, do you have to use a spinner adapter if you set the array in a spinner to a string array declared in strings.xml?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any kind of adapter. For example I use a CursorAdapter to populate from sqlite.